# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I know this question has been asked several times and i saw some solutions here on Stackoverflow, but after trying every possible problem solving tips out i still could not get a hang of my error. i tried to uninstall from my Package Manager but it seems i have 2types of .Net Entity Framework in one project. (4.5 and 6.0). After trying to uninstall either of them it says: Unable to uninstall 'EntityFramework 6.0.2' because 'EntityFramework.Extras 0.9.4.0, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact 6.0.2' depend on it. Likewise the 4.5. Please any suggestion would be appreciated.thanks

> Server Error in '/' Application. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045) Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'
>   could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework  (Partial) WRN: Partial
>   binding information was supplied for an assembly: WRN: Assembly Name:
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework | Domain ID: 2 WRN: A
>   partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect
>   assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual
>   identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name,
>   version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///c:/users/sarah/documents/visual studio
>   2013/Projects/WingtipToys/WingtipToys/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   c:\users\sarah\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WingtipToys\WingtipToys\bin Calling assembly :
>   (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\users\sarah\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WingtipToys\WingtipToys\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Sarah\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Sarah/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/89fcbef3/584b953e/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Sarah/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/89fcbef3/584b953e/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///c:/users/sarah/documents/visual studio
>   2013/Projects/WingtipToys/WingtipToys/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.DLL.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   c:\users\sarah\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WingtipToys\WingtipToys\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Sarah\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 ERR:
>   Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131045). Probing
>   terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +218    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +9915300
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18447

Comment: try updating your nuget packages

Comment: i did but same error still

Comment: are you building projects to target framework 4.0?

Comment: If so target 4.5 and rebuild

Comment: whew!!! Did that too, same error. But is it possible to have 2 entity framework referenced by one project? because even though my target is 4.5, somehow i cant get rid of the 6.0 because my database is attached to it. I have no idea what else to do

Comment: How about uninstalling the other packages first?, extras and sqlserver compact. Sorry with this back and fourth, these are often tricky to get working

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the references to EntityFramework.Extras 0.9.4.0 and EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact 6.0.2 first and then uninstall/reinstall EF through nuget.

Comment: i had to start my project all over again, thankfully I'm able to select the package i want for a particular project. Disadvantage is the time i wasted, i spent a whole day trying to solve the issue and to no avail. But thanks guys for helping out